# Ionic data synchronization between screen and controller

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

i'm beginner on ionic framework, i'm passing for problem with data synchronization, the interface call a function on controller, this function remove a item of a array **lupulos**, which is vinculed by angular **ng-repeat="lupulo in lupulos"**, but, when a list of a item it's removed of a local database with success, it's made a spllice to remove a item from **lupulos**, the item is removed from controlller, but in the screen, the record still there, it's only disappear when i make some interaction in a screen, click in another item of a list, or leave the screen and return for example. how i make this refresh automatically? it was no longer to operate automatically?

sellAppCtrl.controller('LupuloCtrl', function ($scope, $location, $ionicPlatform, $ionicPopup) {

```
//list of records
$scope.lupulos = [];

//Delete record when confirmed pop up   
$scope.deleteLupulo = function (lupulo) {

    var confirmPopup = $ionicPopup.confirm({
        title: 'Remoção de lúpulo',
        template: 'Are you sure you want to delete hop ' + lupulo.nomelupulo + '?'
    });

    confirmPopup.then(function (res) {
        if (res) {
            //Deleta o objeto, passando o DOC como parametro.
            beerDb.remove(lupulo, function (err, response) {
                if (err) {
                    return console.log(err);
                }
                console.log(response);
                //when record whas success removed from database, remove from list too
                $scope.lupulos.splice($scope.lupulos.indexOf(lupulo), 1);
            });
        } else {

        }
    });

}

$ionicPlatform.ready(function () {
    //Retrieve data from de local database
    $scope.retrieveLupulos();
});
```

});

database is on the app.js

```
var sellApp = angular.module('starter', ['ionic', 'angular-datepicker', 'starter.controllers']);
var beerDb = new PouchDB("beer");

sellApp.run(function($ionicPlatform) {
    $ionicPlatform.ready(function() {
        if (window.StatusBar) {
            StatusBar.styleDefault();
        }
    });
})
```

Comment: Would you like to show us your controller code? I guess the problem might be the way to call the remove function in your controller.

Comment: added a controller code

Comment: One more last quastion is what is `beerDb`? I guess HTML5 indexeddb or something.

Comment: the beerDb it's a PouchDB http://pouchdb.com/ a Javascript database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap your splice function call by `$scope.$apply` to update view.

The code will be like below.

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.lupulos.splice(...
});
```

The reason why you need to wrap it by `$scope.$apply` is that angularjs doesn't support the asynchronous callback function of 3rd party library(for instance jquery ajax callback function) to update view automatically.
If you use angularjs service(for instance `$http`, `$resource`...), you don't need to do this.

[Official document is here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply)

Comment: Thanks, solve my problem! indeed, before i did this tests with Javascript database, i did some REST operations, using Angular $http, and i dont had problems.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use $scope.$apply() to inform the view it needs to update:

```
$scope.$apply(function(){
    $scope.lupulos.splice($scope.lupulos.indexOf(lupulo), 1);
});
```